# Finding the fewest number of arrays whose union matches another array

Tags: arrays, ruby, optimization

Given an arbitrary number of arrays placed into an array:

```
a = [1, 2, 4]
b = [2, 4]
c = [3]
d = [1, 2]

arrays = [a, b, c, d]
```

I would like to select the fewest number of these arrays which union to match the array `[1, 2, 3, 4]` in ruby, i.e. the "correct" answer is `[a, c]` and not `[b, c, d]`.

For my purposes, it does not matter if the fewest number of arrays overlap at all, just that they can fulfill the criterion of matching the desired array.

I can imagine several brute force solutions (e.g. a nested loop that unions each element with every other element), but I'm wondering if there is an optimal/elegant method to get this result.

Comment: You can reduce the number of possible combinations by removing any array whose elements are already contained in another array. In your example, both `b` and `d` are covered by `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure (I'd wager the problem is NP-complete) that one must just check combinations, beginning with combinations of one array, then, if that is unsuccessful, checking combinations of two arrays, and so on.

```
def minimal_cover(arr, target)
  (1..arr.size).each do |n|
    arr.combination(n).each { |a| return a if (target - a.reduce(:|)).empty? }
  end
  nil
end

a = [1, 2, 4]
b = [2, 4]
c = [3]
d = [1, 2]
arrays = [a, b, c, d]
target = [1, 2, 3, 4]

minimal_cover(arrays, target)
  #=> [[1, 2, 4], [3]]
```

Comment: It looks like a variant of subset-sum with arrays instead of integers. Subset-sum is indeed NP-complete.

Comment: Thanks for answering! This is pretty much the solution I came to. Had forgotten about the `combination` function though, that's a handy thing. Marking yours as correct, thanks!